# Testing for Mean Difference in Panel Data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, panel-data

I have the following problem where I try to test for difference in means between two groups of individuals in a panel data, however, I suspect that due to how I construct the two groups there is dependence within and between the samples.

**Description of data**

I have panel data with daily observations taken over three months for six hundred individuals. Observations are indicators (0 or 1) and meet the following requirement 
$$\sum_{t} x_{i,t} \leq 1 \qquad \forall i,$$ 
where $i$ is individual's id and $x_{i,t}$ is the observed value for individual $i$ on day $t$. For the purpose of this question, assume that observation indicates whether the individual passed away on particular date. Then $x_{007,\text{3/14}}$ would indicate whether individual $007$ passed away on 14 March.

I also have a relationship matrix between all individuals, i.e., a dataframe with all values of *id* in both column headers and row headers. The values, either 0 or 1, indicate whether two individuals are related.

```
   Observations
+-----+-----+-----+
| dt  |  id | val |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1/1 | 000 |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1/1 | 001 |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1/1 | 002 |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| ... | ... | ... |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 4/1 | 000 |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| 4/1 | 001 |  0  |
+-----+-----+-----+

    Relationships
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |000|001|...|599|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|000| 0 | 0 |...| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|001| 0 | 0 |...| 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|003| 1 | 0 |...| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|...|...|...|...|...|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|598| 0 | 1 |...| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|599| 0 | 0 |...| 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

**The task**

Now, my goal is to test the hypothesis that related individuals "affect" one another in a way that if my relative has recently passed away, then I am more likely to pass away within the next three days than someone who hasn't lost a relative today.

What I have done is:

1. Identify all deaths.
2. For each death (date $t$, id $i$):

   1. Identify all relatives and non-relatives who are still alive on day $t$.
   2. Calculate death ratio among relatives within the following three days, i.e., dates $[t, t+3]$ (inclusive so four days total).
   3. Calculate death ratio among non-relatives within the same time-frame as above, $[t, t+3]$.
   4. Append the two ratios to two lists.
3. Use Kruskal to test for difference in means between the two lists.

**The question**

Now, I am unsure that this is a correct approach. I think that the samples in my two lists are not independent. Furthermore, I suspect that there are stretches of dates when individuals are more likely to pass away regardless of their relationships. Should I change my approach to this problem? Is there a different test that I should use? I appreciate any help and references to similar problems, papers, textbooks.

Comment: Your data format is strange, just say you have one observation per person, which is a death date (but could be censored if the person is still alive.) Then you have a group/family indicator, and the questions is if the dates within groups are more similar than dates in different groups.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen good point, it does look strange. It is because I tried to simplify my problem. I will edit my question later today. Thank you for your feedback.